# Change Y Axis in Image Chart

Tags: google-visualization, image-charts

I am trying to create a Image chart - Line chart . I want my Y AXIS- from 6 to 9 . But I am not able to control the variable

```
<img src="https://image-charts.com/chart?cht=lc&chd=a:6.17,7.18,8.8|7.17,6.8,8.8&chs=600x600&chco=00FF00,0000FFFF&chyt=y&chyr=1,6.1,9.1|2,6.1,9.1" classed="displayed" alt="Graph: no internet connection."
        align="center" />"
```

How to change the chyr parameter to control . IS my parameters wrong

Answer (score 1):

Not very familiar with "image-charts", but, you can use this [chart editor](https://editor.image-charts.com/#https:/image-charts.com/chart?cht=bb&chd=t:10,10,30,_,30,40,35&chf=b0,lg,90,03a9f47C,0,3f51b57C,1&chxt=y,x&chs=711x313&chl=label%201%7Clabel%202&chma=0,50,50&chg=20,20)<sup>1</sup> for configure your charts.

I modified the code - *without really knowing the correct values to supply* - as follows:

```
https://image-charts.com/chart?cht=lc&chd=a:9.17,7.18,8.8|7.17,6.8,8.8&chs=600x600&chco=00FF00,0000FFFF&chyt=y&chyr=1,6.1,9.1|2,6.1,9.1
```

I changed:

```
chd=a:6.17
```

For:

```
chd=a:9.17
```

The result is:

```html
<img src="https://image-charts.com/chart?cht=lc&chd=a:9.17,7.18,8.8|7.17,6.8,8.8&chs=600x600&chco=00FF00,0000FFFF&chyt=y&chyr=1,6.1,9.1|2,6.1,9.1" classed="displayed" alt="Graph: no internet connection." align="center" />
```

In case this modification didn't work for you, please, check the documentation and test the [chart editor](https://editor.image-charts.com/#https:/image-charts.com/chart?cht=bb&chd=t:10,10,30,_,30,40,35&chf=b0,lg,90,03a9f47C,0,3f51b57C,1&chxt=y,x&chs=711x313&chl=label%201%7Clabel%202&chma=0,50,50&chg=20,20).

---

<sup>1</sup> Editor found at the [documentation](https://documentation.image-charts.com/reference/chart-type/).